# Output file from an .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, download

I'm trying to output a file from my DownloadFile.aspx page using code-behind C# code. I do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFilePath = @"C:\Server\file";
    string strFileName = @"downloaded.txt";

    long uiFileSize = new FileInfo(strFilePath).Length;

    using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(strFilePath))
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + strFileName + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", uiFileSize.ToString());

        Response.OutputStream.CopyTo(file);

        Response.End();
    }
}
```

This works, but when the file is downloaded & saved its contents are just an HTML page.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're copying the streams backward. Should be:

```
file.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: Another alternative so you don't have to deal with the stream stuff is `Response.WriteFile(strFilePath);`

Answer (score 3):

Clear the response before sending the file, and use the TransmitFile method instead.

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.TransmitFile("FilePath.ext")
    Response.End()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx

Comment: +1 for `TransmitFile` vs `WriteFile`. Didn't notice that there were two different ones, and this one looks better.

Comment: Thanks. Clearing the header might be a good idea :) The reason I went with my longer method was because I need to change the file name that's being downloaded.